# UIView animateWithDuration doesn't animate cornerRadius variation

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cornerradius

I'm trying to animate the change of the `cornerRadius` of a `UIView` instance `layer`, but the variation of the `cornerRadius` takes place immediately.

Here's the code:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    
    [view.layer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
    
}];
```

Thanks everybody who is going to give me any tips.

**EDIT:**

I managed to animate this property using `Core Animation`, using a `CABasicAnimation`.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.duration = 1.0;
[viewToAnimate.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"cornerRadius"];
[animation.layer setCornerRadius:0.0];
```

Comment: Try this, to make your animation to stick to new values: 
`animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;`
`animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;`

Comment: @MohammadAbdurraafay No, please don't. That is the wrong way of making an animation "stick".

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Why shouldn't `animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` be used? You give no alternative suggestions either here or in your answer.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist The link didn't attach.

Comment: @user1763532 Let's try that again: [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17435092/608157) explains some problems with `removeOnCompletion = NO` and gives one alternate solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (round) UIView resizing with AutoLayout... how to animate cornerRadius during the resize animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713244/circular-round-uiview-resizing-with-autolayout-how-to-animate-cornerradius)

Comment: @robmayoff The other one may be a duplicate as it was asked only two months ago, whereas this was asked 4 years ago.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one is older. It matters which one has a working answer. (If age mattered, stackoverflow wouldn't offer the option to close this one as a duplicate of that one.)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Corner radius is not animatable in `animateWithDuration:animations:`.

---

## What the documentation says about view animations.

As the [section on Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) in the "View Programming Guide for iOS" says

> Both UIKit and Core Animation provide support for animations, but the level of support provided by each technology varies. In UIKit, animations are performed using UIView objects

The **full list of properties** that you can animate using either the older

```
[UIView beginAnimations:context:];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:];
// Change properties here...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or the newer

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:];
```

(that you are using) are:

- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform (CGAffineTransform, not the CATransform3D)
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch

As you can see, `cornerRadius` is not in the list.

### Some confusion

UIView animations is really only meant for animating view properties. What confuses people is that you can also animate the same properties on the layer inside the UIView animation block, i.e. the frame, bounds, position, opacity, backgroundColor. So people see layer animations inside `animateWithDuration` and believe that they can animate any view property in there.

The same section goes on to say:

> In places where you want to perform more sophisticated animations, or animations not supported by the UIView class, you can use Core Animation and the view’s underlying layer to create the animation. Because view and layer objects are intricately linked together, changes to a view’s layer affect the view itself.

A few lines down you can read the list of Core Animation animatable properties where you see this one:

> - The layer’s border (including whether the layer’s corners are rounded)

So to animate the `cornerRadius` you **need** to use Core Animation as you've already said in your updated question (and answer). I just added tried to explain why its so.

---

## Some extra clarification

When people read the documentations that says that `animateWithDuration` is the recommended way of animating it is easy to believe that it is trying to replace CABasicAnimation, CAAnimationGroup, CAKeyframeAnimation, etc. but its really not. Its replacing the `beginAnimations:context:` and `commitAnimations` that you seen above.

Comment: Good answer. Props for pointing out all the documentation as well.

Comment: Perfect answer. Helped a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: This changed in iOS 11, please refer to my answer

Answer (score 25):

I use this extension to animate change of corner radius:

```
extension UIView
{
    func animateCornerRadius(from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval)
    {
        CATransaction.begin()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
        animation.fromValue = from
        animation.toValue = to
        animation.duration = duration
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
            self?.layer.cornerRadius = to
        }
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked really well. You don't really need the from field since it should really always be `layer.cornerRadius`.

Comment: Thank you, worked well inside my UIView.animate block, ie combining the movement of a UIView with a change in its cornerRadius

Comment: It's animatable as of iOS 11 https://useyourloaf.com/blog/masked-and-animated-corners/

Answer (score 15):

A corner radius variation can be animated but the only way to do so is to use a CABasicAnimation. Hope this helps somebody out there.

Answer (score 14):

Starting in [iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator) you can actually animate cornerRadius:

```
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 3.0, curve: .easeIn) {
    square.layer.cornerRadius = 20
}.startAnimation()
```

Comment: Its available from iOS 10+.

Answer (score 13):

You can implement UIView animation as here: http://maniacdev.com/2013/02/ios-uiview-category-allowing-you-to-set-up-customizable-animation-properties

```m
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
animation.duration = DURATION;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
animation.toValue = @(NEW_CORNER_RADIUS);
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"setCornerRadius:"];
```

Comment: Since iOS 11 cornerRadius is animatable property

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like that's one of the animatable properties.

See here for the full list:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: Well... if you use the old approach for animations, it will work... But if you try to use the approach suggested by Apple, than it doesn't animate.

Comment: @singingAtom animateWithDuration: and CABasicAnimations is actually not the same thing so there is no new or old approach. animateWithDuration is not a part of Core Animation and can only animate view properties, (cornerRadius is a layer property). The real **old approach** that animateWithDuration replaces is [UIView beginAnimations:context:] and [UIView commitAnimation] which work exactly the same way as the new approach. Apple suggests using animateWithDuration: for view properties and continues on to say that you should use Core Animation for more advanced animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this property animatable in `+[UIView animateWithDuration:]` by implementing `-[actionForLayer:forKey]` in your view class.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669051/how-do-i-create-a-smoothly-resizable-circular-uiview) for an example of how.

Answer (score 0):

**CornerRadius property is animatable**

***working code is below***

//layer init

```
let imageLayer = CALayer() 
imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.0, width: tenPercent, height: tenPercent)
imageLayer.contents = imageNew.cgImage
imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
```

// animation init

```
let animationCornerRadius = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
animationCornerRadius.beginTime =  0.01
animationCornerRadius.duration = CFTimeInterval(5)
animationCornerRadius.fromValue = 1
animationCornerRadius.toValue = tenPercent / 2
animationCornerRadius.fillMode = .forwards
animationCornerRadius.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
imageLayer.add(animationCornerRadius , forKey: "cornerRadius")
```