# How do I create a smoothly resizable circular UIView?

Tags: uiview, core-graphics, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to create a UIView which shows a semitransparent circle with an opaque border inside its bounds.  I want to be able to change the bounds in two ways - inside a `-[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` block and in a pinch gesture recogniser action which fires several times a second.  I've tried three approaches based on answers elsewhere on SO, and none are suitable.

1. Setting the corner radius of the view's layer in `layoutSubviews` gives smooth translations, but the view doesn't stay circular during animations; it seems that cornerRadius isn't animatable.
2. Drawing the circle in `drawRect:` gives a consistently circular view, but if the circle gets too big then resizing in the pinch gesture gets choppy because the device is spending too much time redrawing the circle.
3. Adding a CAShapeLayer and setting its path property in `layoutSublayersOfLayer`, which doesn't animate inside UIView animations since path isn't implicitly animatable.

Is there a way for me to create a view which is consistently circular and smoothly resizable?  Is there some other type of layer I could use to take advantage of the hardware acceleration?

UPDATE

A commenter has asked me to expand on what I mean when I say that I want to change the bounds inside a `-[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` block.  In my code, I have a view which contains my circle view. The circle view (the version that uses cornerRadius) overrides `-[setBounds:]` in order to set the corner radius:

```
-(void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = fminf(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2.0;
    [super setBounds:bounds];
}
```

The bounds of the circle view are set in `-[layoutSubviews]`:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // some other layout is performed and circleRadius and circleCenter are
    // calculated based on the properties and current size of the view.

    self.circleView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, circleRadius*2, circleRadius*2);
    self.circleView.center = circleCenter;
}
```

The view is sometimes resized in animations, like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 animations:^(void) {
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
    [myView setNeedsLayout];
    [myView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

but during these animations, if I draw the circle view using a layer with a cornerRadius, it goes funny shapes.  I can't pass the animation duration in to layoutSubviews so I need to add the right animation within `-[setBounds]`.

Comment: 1 should stay circular as long as you animate the corner radius and the size together (maybe in a CAAnimationGroup). At all times the cornerRadius needs to be half the width and the width needs to be the same as the height.

Comment: I need it to work inside animateWithDuration:animations: - will that work with a CAAnimationGroup?

Comment: animateWithDuration: does the grouping itself so the explicit animation group is not necessary. Animating the corner radius together with the size should work as long as it remains half the side of the rectangle.

Comment: Hmmm... well, it doesn't. What happens is that the new corner radius shows immediately, and then the animation proceeds from there.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948167/uiview-animatewithduration-doesnt-animate-cornerradius-variation) where a user has the same problem with cornerRadius.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, You can only animate view properties inside animateWithDuration: (e.g. frame, bound, center, alpha, backgroundColor, transform (not the 3D) and stretchMode). Otherwise you will have to use Core Animation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular (round) UIView resizing with AutoLayout... how to keep it a circle during the resize animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713244/circular-round-uiview-resizing-with-autolayout-how-to-keep-it-a-circle-duri)

Comment: @robmayoff the other way round, surely?  That question's 5 hours old, this one is from 2012.

Comment: Yes but the other one has an answer that works under current iOS.

Comment: @robmayoff So? It's the question that's a duplicate, not the answer.

Comment: Closing that question as a duplicate of this one would not help people find a working answer. Closing this question as a duplicate of that one would. Stack overflow should help people find working answers.

Comment: @robmayoff so post the updated answer here, not to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With many thanks to David, this is the solution I found.  In the end what turned out to be the key to it was using the view's `-[actionForLayer:forKey:]` method, since that's used inside UIView blocks instead of whatever the layer's `-[actionForKey]` returns.

```
@implementation SGBRoundView

-(CGFloat)radiusForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    return fminf(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height) / 2;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.opaque = NO;
        self.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor purpleColor] CGColor];
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = [self radiusForBounds:self.bounds];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = [self radiusForBounds:bounds];
    [super setBounds:bounds];
}

-(id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event
{
    id<CAAction> action = [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:event];

    if ([event isEqualToString:@"cornerRadius"])
    {
        CABasicAnimation *boundsAction = (CABasicAnimation *)[self actionForLayer:layer forKey:@"bounds"];
            if ([boundsAction isKindOfClass:[CABasicAnimation class]] && [boundsAction.fromValue isKindOfClass:[NSValue class]])
        {            
            CABasicAnimation *cornerRadiusAction = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
            cornerRadiusAction.delegate = boundsAction.delegate;
            cornerRadiusAction.duration = boundsAction.duration;
            cornerRadiusAction.fillMode = boundsAction.fillMode;
            cornerRadiusAction.timingFunction = boundsAction.timingFunction;

            CGRect fromBounds = [(NSValue *)boundsAction.fromValue CGRectValue];
            CGFloat fromRadius = [self radiusForBounds:fromBounds];
            cornerRadiusAction.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromRadius];

            return cornerRadiusAction;
        }
    }

    return action;
}

@end
```

By using the action that the view provides for the bounds, I was able to get the right duration, fill mode and timing function, and most importantly delegate - without that, the completion block of UIView animations didn't run.

The radius animation follows that of the bounds in almost all circumstances - there are a few edge cases that I'm trying to iron out, but it's basically there.  It's also worth mentioning that the pinch gestures are still sometimes jerky - I guess even the accelerated drawing is still costly.

Comment: This was really helpful, and works almost perfectly. I would just point out that I think you should add the cornerRadiusAction animation to the layer, rather than returning it (the original action should be returned) so that the animation end is correctly sent (in my case the UIView animate block never called the end block unless I returned the original action). Also, you will come across problems whenever the animation is different from the standard (I hacked together a method for a CASpringAnimation but it's private API).

Comment: Your solution works great, except CASpringAnimation was an issue for me too - my solution is to use `CABasicAnimation *cornerRadiusAction = [boundsAction copy];`, and then simply set the `.keypath` and `.fromValue` properties separately. All the other `.delegate` etc properties are copied.

Comment: In swift, I get an error when casting the `CAAction` to `CABasicAnimation`. Any suggestions?

Comment: This approach can be modified to work again in newer version of iOS, and works for autorotation animations. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714554/77567).

Answer (score 17):

As the [section on Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) in the "View Programming Guide for iOS" says

> Both UIKit and Core Animation provide support for animations, but the level of support provided by each technology varies. In UIKit, animations are performed using UIView objects

The **full list of properties** that you can animate using either the older

```
[UIView beginAnimations:context:];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:];
// Change properties here...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

or the newer

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:];
```

(that you are using) are:

- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform (CGAffineTransform, not the CATransform3D)
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch

What confuses people is that you can also animate the same properties on the layer inside the UIView animation block, i.e. the frame, bounds, position, opacity, backgroundColor.

The same section goes on to say:

> In places where you want to perform more sophisticated animations, or animations not supported by the UIView class, you can use Core Animation and the view’s underlying layer to create the animation. Because view and layer objects are intricately linked together, changes to a view’s layer affect the view itself.

A few lines down you can read the list of Core Animation animatable properties where you see this one:

> - The layer’s border (including whether the layer’s corners are rounded)

---

There are at least two good options for achieving the effect that you are after:

- Animating the corner radius
- Using a CAShapeLayer and animating the path

Both of these require that you do the animations with Core Animation. You can create a CAAnimationGroup and add an array of animations to it if you need multiple animations to run as one.

---

#### Update:

Fixing things with as few code changes as possible would be done by doing the corner radius animation on the layer at the "same time" as the other animations. *I put quotations marks around same time since it is not guaranteed that animations that are not in the same group will finish at exactly the same time.* Depending on what other animations you are doing it might be better to use only basic animations and animations groups. If you are applying changes to many different views in the same view animation block then maybe you could look into CATransactions.

The below code animates the frame and corner radius much like you describe.

```
UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100)];
[[circle layer] setCornerRadius:50];
[[circle layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor]];
[[circle layer] setBorderWidth:2.0];
[[circle layer] setBackgroundColor:[[[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
[[self view] addSubview:circle];

CGFloat animationDuration = 4.0; // Your duration
CGFloat animationDelay = 3.0; // Your delay (if any)

CABasicAnimation *cornerRadiusAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
[cornerRadiusAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0]]; // The current value
[cornerRadiusAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0]]; // The new value
[cornerRadiusAnimation setDuration:animationDuration];
[cornerRadiusAnimation setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime() + animationDelay];

// If your UIView animation uses a timing funcition then your basic animation needs the same one
[cornerRadiusAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

// This will keep make the animation look as the "from" and "to" values before and after the animation
[cornerRadiusAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
[[circle layer] addAnimation:cornerRadiusAnimation forKey:@"keepAsCircle"];
[[circle layer] setCornerRadius:10.0]; // Core Animation doesn't change the real value so we have to.

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                      delay:animationDelay
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations:^{
                     [[circle layer] setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 20, 20)]; // Arbitrary frame ...
                     // You other UIView animations in here...
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Maybe you have your completion in here...
                 }];
```

Comment: OK - is there a way of working out that I'm in an existing UIView animation block so I can add the core animation to the setter?

Comment: @Simon I'm not sure what you mean with "to the setter" I've updated my answer with some sample code that uses both a basic animation and a animateWithDuration: block to show you how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks - that's good example code, even if it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  What I mean by "to the setter" is that I want to override setBounds: on my view class in a way that is aware of when it's within a UIView animation block and adds the animation with the correct parameters when it's called.  I'll update the question to explain.

Comment: Your answer led me to the right answer, so I've upvoted some of your other answers - hope that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in iOS 11, UIKit animates `cornerRadius` if you change it inside an animation block.

Answer (score 0):

The path property of a CAShapeLayer isn't **implicitly** animatable, but it is animatable. It should be pretty easy to create a CABasicAnimation that changes the size of the circle path. Just makes sure that the path has the same number of control points (e.g. changing the radius of a full-circle arc.) If you change the number of control points, things get really strange. "Results are undefined", according to the documentaiton.

Comment: How do I make that work with animateWithDuration:animations: ?

Comment: You don't. You have to create a CABasicAnimation object and add it to your view's layer. You can do that the same time as a view animation.

Comment: Ah. I need it to work with the UIView animation methods, as I'm animating other objects at the same time.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with implicit vs. explicit animations but more with view property animations vs. layer property animations.

Comment: @David, the term implicit animations is specific to animations that happen automatically when you change an animatable property of a layer. So it is both. The path property of a shape layer is an odd case. It is animatable, but not implicitly. If you change a shape layer's path directly, the change doesn't animate, but if you do it from a CAAnimation, it will animate the change.

Comment: @simon, you can create both UView animations and CABasicAnimations at the same time, that run concuIrrently.

Comment: @DuncanC You are right. I thought that you meant that animations inside animateWithDuration: was implicit (silly me). I never tried to implicitly animate the path of a shape layer because I always thought it would go too fast but now I tried. I doesn't animate implicitly. It's always good to learn something new. Thanks!