# How can I get the translated position of a CALayer after I have already translated it once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, calayer

I am just trying to translate the layer back to its original position, after already have translated it once.  I can always store the layer position I translated to in a property, but it seems like there is a better way.  I am doing something like this to translate my layer:

```
CABasicAnimation *slide = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
slide.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:translationValue];
slide.duration = duration;
slide.removedOnCompletion = NO;
slide.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
slide.autoreverses = NO;

[layer addAnimation:slide forKey:KEYPATH_POSITION];
```

I was trying to do something like the following, but this has no animation, it just appears back to its original position.

```
CABasicAnimation *slide = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
slide.toValue = [layer valueForKey:@"position"];
slide.duration = duration;
slide.removedOnCompletion = NO;
slide.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
slide.autoreverses = NO;

[layer addAnimation:slide forKey:KEYPATH_POSITION];
```

Comment: `removedOnCompletion = NO` is your problem. Set the model value instead and remove the animation when it completes

Comment: [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17435092/608157) could be helpful (repeated animations with removedOnCompletion=NO).

Comment: Sweet, I understand this a lot more now.  I can totally see why your way is better.  Would you then just keep the original starting point in a property?  So that I can just set the transform to be that point, when I want the layer to move back?

Comment: If you are using a transform like your first example then you can simply set it back the identity transform to move back

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand.  I tried doing something like the following but it didn't work:
CGPoint currentPosition = [[layer valueForKeyPath:KEYPATH_POSITION] CGPointValue];
slide.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPosition];

Comment: Ah, I figured it out.  If you want to write an answer, I'll mark your answer, if not, I'll just post code I'm using as an answer.  Thank you!

Comment: It's ok. You can post the answer yourself :)