# Rotate imageView random

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, arc4random

I am trying to get the image view to rotate random degree between 360 and 720. So I want the image view to rotate once(360 degrees), and then again rotate a random degree(0 to 360)

```
func rotateRandom2(){
    let lower : UInt32 = 360
    let upper : UInt32 = 720
    let diceRoll = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(upper - lower) + lower)
    let degree =  0.0174532925 as CGFloat
    let rotate = diceRoll
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,      animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.bottleImageView.transform, rotate)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: first: the values should be radians, meaning 0 - 2PI instead of 0 - 360. second: you might have to use a CABasicAnimation and specify that it is an additive animation.

Comment: @luk2302 - I have NO idea how to do that(?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426802/using-cabasicanimation-to-rotate-a-uiimageview-more-than-once

Comment: Shouldn't you be multiplying something by `degree`.  `let rotate = diceRoll * degree` perhaps?

Comment: What problems do you face with what you have tried? From other comments, it looks like you want to find our the difference between radians and degrees, and which is used for rotation.

Comment: Note that `degree` is 1 degree in radians, so `360 * degree` is 360 degrees in radians.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29179878/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CABasicAnimation to animate z rotation. You can do as follow:

```
let rotateView = CABasicAnimation()
let randonAngle = arc4random_uniform(361) + 360
rotateView.fromValue = 0
rotateView.toValue = Float(randonAngle) * Float(M_PI) / 180.0
rotateView.duration = 1
rotateView.repeatCount = 0
rotateView.removedOnCompletion = false
rotateView.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
rotateView.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
view.layer.addAnimation(rotateView, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
```

Comment: Good one! Thanks. A quick questions: How can i detect if the imageView has stopped rotating, without using a timer?

Comment: I have never used Objective-C. I have only used Swift, so i do not know how to use that code for Swift.

Comment: Feel free to open another question asking how to add a completion handler to a cabasic animation. Don't forget to select the checkmark below the votes counter if that answer answered your original question

Comment: You can also use a delay function to execute what you want after a specific time, in that case the time to complete the rotation

Comment: @JamesOfferd note: if you want 720 inclusive you need to use arc4random_uniform(361) + 360